# Why my GUI in java Freeze when I start calculation in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, concurrency

I am developing a java application

but my application Freeze when I start the process of my application

therefore I can update my GUI during the process

do you guys have any idea how to fixed this ?

I'll appreciate for your reply thx

Guys I already try this but it still freezes the GUI

here are my Code

```
final String key = keywords;
        final int dept = dep;
        final double rele = relevance;

        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Map, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Map doInBackground() {
                final Map resultMap = focusedCrawlingMain.Search(key, dept, rele);  

                return resultMap;
            }

            public void Done(Map dataMap) {
                final List resultList = (List) dataMap.get("relevantList");
                List resultListValue = (List) dataMap.get("relevantListScore");
                int size = resultList.size();

                newData = new String[size][3];
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    newData[i][0] = String.valueOf(i+1);
                    newData[i][1] = String.valueOf(resultList.get(i));
                    newData[i][2] = String.valueOf(resultListValue.get(i));
                    model.addRow((new Object[]{newData[i][0],newData[i][1],newData[i][2]}));
                }
            }
        };
        worker.run();
```

Comment: Why is this not a real question?  Seems to me like a really good question, but it's probably been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: @Carlo : I really don't know much about SwingWorker thingy, but why not you start a new Thread from your main method as suggested by Darin Dimitrov, and perform your calculations in that thread, that won't let your GUI freeze in any way.  Regards

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali since I dont know how to use MultiThreading can you show it to me?

Comment: @Carlo : Simply make a new Class which implements Runnable and inside it's run method, do your calculations. And in your main Method, write this Thread threadName = new Thread(new CalculationClass()); threadName.start();   That will do i guess. Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali _And in your main Method, write this Thread threadName = new Thread(....) ... .start()_ wrong (or least only half of the story) when it comes to Swing: in the end, properties of the ui must be updated and that update _must_ happen on the EDT. That's where SwingWorker comes to help, as it allows to cleanly separate the background thread and the EDT and manages the communication from the former to the latter

Comment: @Carlo: a) looks like you didn't read the api doc of SwingWorker (hint: worker.run() is _not_ the way to start it) b) the method to override is _done_ (not Done)

Comment: @kleopatra : Thankx for the info, that's the part i dont know about SwingWorker. Then he can write, what i said inside his EDT, that might will do, seems like. I can for an example give him a code for a messenger, where i did exactly what i said, if that can help him in some way.  Regards

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Answer (score 4):

I believe that worker.run() might cause some trouble. If i didn't misunderstand your code you should actually call worker.execute().

Also, move as much of the computations in the Done method to doInBackground, as possible. The Done method executes on the Event Dispatch Thread, which freezes up the GUI, expecially noticable when running long computations.

Comment: good catch :-) another slight glitch in the question: _Done_ is never called, as it doesn't override any super method ...

Answer (score 2):

You could perform the calculation in a separate thread than the main GUI thread. Here's [an article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) you may take a look at which also covers the different things you should be aware when doing multithreading in a swing application.